# return true if circle c overlaps any other circle in the arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, geometry

I have an assigment in my beginners class in coding, in java. This is the assignment (translated from swedish to english by me, therefor I'm sorry in advance);

The class CircleList keeps track of a number of circles. Implement the class.

Guidance

- This task should, not only give practice in using ArrayList, but also give practice in breaking down a problem in several methods. Therefor you should use the method `overlaps`inside of the method `add`.
- And for the method `overlaps` to be easier to write, you should, in `overlaps` use the private method `circleOverlaps`.
- Two circles overlaps if the distance between their origos are less than the sum of their radiuses.

The class Circle looks like this;

```
class Circle {
    private double radius;
    private double x;
    private double y;

   /** Constructs a circle with the radie radius and the 
       center in  x, y. */
    public Circle(double x, double y, double radius) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    /** Returns the x coordinate of the center. */
    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    /** Returns the y coordinate of the center. */
    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    /** Returns the radius. */
    public double radius() {
        return radius;
    }

     /** Returns the area. */
    public double area() {
        return Math.PI * radius * radius;
    }
}
```

And this is what I've come up with so far, (the methods were already declared but not implemented);

```
public class CircleList {
   private ArrayList<Circle> circles;

    /** Constructs an empty list for circles. */
    public CircleList() {
        circles = new ArrayList<Circle>();
    }

    /** Adds the circle c to the list if it not ovelaps
        with any circle in the list. Return true if 
        circle has been added. */ 
    public boolean add(Circle c) {
          circles.add(c); 
    }

    /** Returns true if the circle c ovelaps with any 
        one circle in this list. */
    public boolean overlaps(Circle c) {

    }

    private boolean circlesOverlaps(Circle c1, Circle c2) {
        double r1 = Circle.radius(c1); //radius, x- & y-value of circle 1 (c1)
        double x1 = Circle.getX(c1);
        double y1 = Circle.getY(c1);

        double r2 = Circle.radius(c2); //radius, x- & y-value för circle 2 (c2)
        double x2 = Circle.getX(c2);
        double y2 = Circle.getY(c2);
        double distance = Math.pow((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2), 0.5);

    if (r2 >= r1 && distance <= (r2 - r1)){  //c1 is inside c2

    }
    else if (r1 >= r2 && distance <= (r1 - r2) ) { //c2 is inside c1

    }
    else if (distance > (r1 + r2)){ //c2 doesn't overlap c1

    }
    else { //c2 overlaps c1

    }


    }
}
```

I don't really know where to start. And I don't really have anyone to ask at the moment. I understand if this is too much to even start with. But thank you anyways.

Take care.

Comment: You said you "_don't really know where to start_".  Well, it looks like you've started, so it would seem you really _did_ know where (:-))  And it appears to be a reasonably good start, too.  Is there a specific question you have about your approach?

Comment: @KevinAnderson thanks for your comment. Well I felt like that wasn't a start... but maybe it was. I just didn't know how to put the methods inside of each other, but I think I'm close to figuring it out now..

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to iterate over all circles and check if the given circle overlaps with any like

```
public boolean overlaps(Circle c) {
        return circles.stream()
                .anyMatch(circle -> circlesOverlaps(c, circle));
    }
```

and you have to return `true` or `false` from your if conditions in `circlesOverlaps` method, depending on whether you consider one circle inside another as an overlap or not for your problem.

One other place you need to correct is

```
public boolean add(Circle c) {
      return circles.add(c); 
}
```

basically adding return as you need to return a boolean based on your return type.